# how to remove this string

Tags: arrays, collections, laravel-5.1

Hi I have an array and I want to remove this string *x000D* from the postaladdress how will I do it ? I have this in an array and I want to remove it. Please assist.

```
[1] => Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection Object
                (
                    [title:protected] => 
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [email] => a22@bkonelearning.com
                            [firstname] => BK
                            [lastname] => Singh
                            [postaladdress] => C 201, Wembley Estate Apts,_x000D_
Rosewood City,_x000D_
(Opposite McDonald's),_x000D_
Sector 50
                            [city] => Gurgaon
                            [pin] => 122016
                            [state] => Haryana
                            [country] => India
                            [phoneno] => 91-9811525663
                            [street] => 
                            [mobileno] => 91-9811525663
                            [gender] => M
                            [occupation] => 
                            [industry] => 
                            [otherarea] => Sector 50
                            [othercity] => 
                            [isreceiveoffers] => 0
                        )

                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the sub-string "x000D" in postaladdress and shift the characters one by one to the left side until 5 characters. Do this for all the occurrences of the string "x000D"